# How to remove padding from Rating Bar in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, ratingbar

i have rating bar on my application and it appears like this:

[image]

I've tried to set padding to 0dp, but nothing changed to the view.

```
 <RatingBar
      android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:isIndicator="false"
      style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"/>
```

Expected result: I am expecting the rating bar with no right padding and bottom padding.

Comment: Update question with parent layout of `RatingBar.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this to my xml code and it solved my problems:

```
android:scaleX="1"
android:scaleY="1"
```

Comment: Yes, but what if you need a smaller scale like in picture?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply adjust this

```
style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.RatingBar.Small"
```

instead of

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Android rating bar is very visually problematic, in which case I would rather use the improvements made by Android users to size each star depending on the size of the object.
Enclosing you a convenient library to work with, I believe this library will solve you a lot of problems with the development.

https://github.com/xckevin/AndroidSmartRatingBar?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7405

Credit to the developer kevin.liu (xckevin).

Answer (score 0):

use scale x and y to reduce the start size and step size to set star size

Answer (score 0):

Try this xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar" />
</LinearLayout>
```